# MVC extension method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, selectlist

I'm trying to write a simple extension method that allows me to select an item in an MVC SelectList by text rather than value.

This is what I came up with but although the item is set as selected while debuging, the returned SelectList has all it's items with selected = false.

Any ideas?

```
 public static SelectList SelectByText(this SelectList list, string TextValue)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.Text == TextValue)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show how you prove that all Selected properties are still false? Is it because of what you seen in the UI output or through examination of the objects directly in the debugger.  Its difficult to see how you could be getting the result you describe.

Comment: Within the if(item.Text == TextValue){} the item has it's selected attribute set to true when the values match but in the overall collection within the debugger the item has it's property set to false. I can't understand what's going on here??

Answer (score 2):

It is not wise to trying to select item on his text instead of a value

anyway,it seems that you have more than one item that satisfies your if statement

to ensure that only one item will be selected you can put a break when you meet condition
like this:

```
if(item.Text == TextValue)
{
  item.Selected = true;
  break;
}
```

cheers